# How can i sendRequest from background to background with chrome extensions API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

Right now i implemented the solution by creating iframes on the background, so it process the request, but its very untrusted solution + overkill, i have something like 400 files that every one of them use sendRequest method, i can't combine them to one file because they load by dependency loader(Pub Sub architecture), now there is another solution that i already made him Proof-of-concept, using MessageChannel & postMessage in the background, but the problem is that for the contentScript or on my definition frontstage, i still need to use chrome API to pass messages between backstage and frontstage.

How do i solve it?:)

Comment: Start with better grammar, then work on making your question clear.

Comment: hmm i'm from israel and my english is not my strong side, this is the best i can do:)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I know what you mean. You have several js files that are all on the background page, and want them to `sendRequest` to eachother. You can do this by not actually doing `sendRequest`s, but calling a function. It's probably better with an example:

**Instead of this:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, respond)
{
    // bla bla handle request
});
```

And this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ message: "hello" }, function(response)
{
    // do something with response
});
```

**You do this:**

```
function handle_message(request, sender, respond)
{
    // bla bla handle request
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(handle_message);
```

And this:

```
handle_message({ message: "hello" }, function(response)
{
    // do something with response
});
```

Of course scripts that are not on the background page will still do `sendRequest`s.